# How to remove the carriage return from string while pasting content to Excel file

Tags: java, excel, carriage-return

I have a problem while pasting my contents (or text) generated by Java code into excel.
The problem is that my Java code generates a String with multiple lines, i.e. with line breaks (`\n`) included.  When I try to copy this content and paste it into an Excel file, I am getting a multiline text with a square box symbol.  I came to know that Windows uses `\r\n` for line breaks and not just `\n`.  I tried to replace my `\n` with `\r\n` and paste the generated text, but I am getting the same square boxes in my Excel file.  Here is my sample code:

```
      String   myString = "a1\nb1";
      String   tmpString =myString.replace("\n","\r\n");
      System.out.println( "Original = " +"\""+myString+"\"");
      System.out.println( "Result   = " +"\""+tmpString+"\"");
```

I have used the **" "** to wrap the text.  When I tried to paste **tmpstring** in Excel, I got the square box.  How can I remove the boxes with **multiple lines in my cell**?

Comment: For something like "ABC\n12", do you get a single box at the end or after each line?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Do you want the carriage return / newline, or don't you? Your title says that you don't, your code is explicitly adding carriage returns when the string has a newline. If you want to get rid of both, use String.replaceAll(), which takes a regex:

```
public static void main(String[] argv)
throws Exception
{
    String s1 = "this\r\nis a test";
    String s2 = s1.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "");
    System.out.println(s2);
}
```

This example finds any occurrence of the characters, and deletes them. You probably want to look for the sequence of characters and replace with a space, but I'll leave that up to you: look at the doc for `java.util.regex.Pattern`.

And I suspect that the "box" is some other character, not a return or newline.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.when try the code posted by u,it also removes the multi lines in my text when i paste it in excel which i dont want to do.and the box returns an ascii value 10 when i check it as a character

Comment: +1 - An old post for you but a useful solution for me :) Thanks!

Comment: should be `[\r\n]` in the line:
`String s2 = s1.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "");`

Comment: @alan-p - it's a regex, so will match either of the characters in brackets, regardless of order.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you copy and paste as usual, then do a search and replace at Excel?

Comment: I have to copy a text programmaticaly to clipboard and then paste it to excel.Here I have mentioned only a sample code.I should not get those text boxes when i paste

Answer (score 0):

If it is any help, I ran this line of code (C#)

```
Clipboard.SetText("1\n2\r\n3");
```

and then Ctrl-V in Excel and 3 cells got filled with A1 got 1, A2 got 2 and A3 got 3. This means that \n and \r\n are handled as expected by Excel. Java strings containing \n and \r\n should work as well. This leads me to believe something's up with the Excel cell settings. Check if the cells are formatted as text.

Other than that, no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    System.out.print("Hello\rHi");
}
```

Due to \r cursor moves to starting of the current line, so "He" of Hello is replaced by "Hi".

Answer (score 0):

Try this =)

```
String s1 = "this\r\nis a test";
String s2 = s1.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
System.out.println(s2);
```