# how to remove the new line character on Excel Cell using POI API

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i am exporting the content to Excel on different cells. I have to populate the html content, where the content may contain multiple lines. I have successfully populated data to excel but one cell displaying new line character.

Can someone please help me to remove the new line character for displaying content having multiple line on a excel cell using POI API.

Comment: I am unclear as to your detired effect if the content is multi-line. If you have multiline content, what do you want in the cell?

Comment: what I wanted is the content having new line character to display in same row. Currently it is displaying in different row.

Comment: To be clear, by different row you mean that the second line is in a different cell in the next row? Or that that contends of a single cell are displayed as two lines and you want them to be displayed in a single line?

Comment: sorry for the confusing question. actually it is problem of my friend and the real problem is, it is displaying the block character at the end of the line where new line character is used. he just want to remove that block character. any solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

The good answer is in this post:

[How to remove the carriage return from string while pasting content to Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612808/how-to-remove-the-carriage-return-from-string-while-pasting-content-to-excel-fil)

`String s2 = s1.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "");`

It's working for me :).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link: [Multi-line text](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-user/200606.mbox/%3C20060607140353.19027.qmail@web32207.mail.mud.yahoo.com%3E)

Basically you need to `setWordWrap(true)` in the `CellStyle`. Then use `\r` as the new-line character.

Answer (score 1):

i think block character means carriage returns  character at end of  each line on excel cell.
so solution is remove the carriage returns character using String function "replaceAll"

Ex:
**String replaceCharacter=originalCharacter.replaceAll("\r"," ");**

in this example '\r' character is replaced by space(" ") by replaceAll function.

Comment: This would not result in a multi-line cell broken where the newline resides, as was requested.