# Why can't I compare this char?

Tags: java

I have a method of replacing all instances of "\n" in a string with the br tag.I get the unclosed character literal error.

```
public static String replaceLineWithBr(String text){
String result="";
    if(text.length()<=1){
 return text;
}else{
 for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++){
    if((text.charAt(i+1)=='n') && (text.charAt(i)=='\')){ //<--- Error line
        result=result+text.substring(0,i)+"<br />"+text.substring(i+2,text.length());
    }else return text;

    }

} 
return text;
```

Why is this code `text.charAt(i)=='\'` not valid?

Comment: use '\n' as a char and compare to it, `text.replace("\n", "<br />");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612808/how-to-remove-the-carriage-return-from-string-while-pasting-content-to-excel-fil

Answer (score 7):

`\` is a special character used to denote the start of carriage control characters such as `\n` and `\t`. It should be escaped to represent a backslash character itself

```
text.charAt(i) == '\\'
```

Answer (score 3):

The "\" character is used to escape characters. 
You must instantiate your char with a double escape, such as char `'\\'`.

**Edit**

Also you could probably spare yourself the trouble and use the `String.replaceAll` method instead, as such:

```
String foo = "foo\nbar\r\nblah";
System.out.println(foo.replaceAll("((\r)?\n)", "<br/>"));
```

Output:

```
foo<br/>bar<br/>blah
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is conceptually incorrect:

```
if((text.charAt(i+1)=='n') && (text.charAt(i)=='\')){ //<--- Error line
```

You seem to be trying to detect `\n`, but that's **one char** (10 on the ASCII table), not two:

```
if (text.charAt(i) == '\n') {
```

Others have already explained why `'\'` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

\\ is substituted as \. That is why you need to write so. You need to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the backslash is used for escaping the next character, so you're escaping the end '. You need to escape the backslash by typing `'\\'`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the '\' character is a special escape character.  You need to use '\\'

[Java Characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

[Illegal Escape Character "\"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257316/illegal-escape-character)