# java - removing CRLF in strings which have double quotes within it

Tags: java

I have a string that holds a value thus -

```
"01/09/2000","09:00","XX","YYYYYYYY YYYY
","XXXXXXX
XXXXXXX ",""~"31/03/2020","","BB","","",""
```

In the above there is a CRLF in the middle of the Y value, a CRLF within the X value and another before the " at the end of the X value. I want a all the CRLF to be removed from the string so it returns like this -

```
"01/09/2000","09:00","XX","YYYYYYYYYYYY","XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",""~"31/03/2020","","BB","","",""
```

What would be the java expression to remove all these?

Comment: looks like you need a csv parsing library. why reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Check this link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612808/how-to-remove-the-carriage-return-from-string-while-pasting-content-to-excel-fil)

Comment: This question has already been posted and answered, here's [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/593716/6664878) that applies directly to your case

Answer (score 1):

You can use replaceAll on String:

```
String input = "A\nB";
input.replaceAll("\n", "");
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `replaceAll` unless you're using regular expressions. There is [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) instead.

Comment: Ok I agree, but when you look into String.replaceAll and String.replace they do almost the same thing, so it seems it is only cosmetic difference.

Comment: You're right; there's very little difference, so there is no reason not to use the correct one.