# why cannot using POI to manipute excel?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
result = cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString();
```

If there is a line breaks in one cell. How to handle this result?

Comment: Possibly this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1612912/1004631

Comment: @coolgirl,I mean I code a function to convert excel file to html. And there is a line breaks in one cell. when converting to html, it cannot parse the line breaks.

Comment: @coolgirl,I have fixed this problem. result = cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString().replaceAll("\\n","<br/>");but I'm not very clear how it recognize whether "\\n" is a String or line breaks . I mean if there is a String "123\\n12345" in one cell, how does it treat is as character "\\n" not line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

row.Cells[i].SetCellValue(MyValues[i].Replace("\r\n", " "));